# Detect level of SSL encryption on a web page (128 or 256) in a firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, ssl-certificate

I am developing a Firefox extension where I need to know the level of SSL encryption of a web page that is loaded. (whether it is a 128 bit encryption or 256 bit encryption).

Basically I need to detect whether the given page is a secure payment page.

Any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the [`nsISSLStatus` interface](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/de483d897af4/security/manager/ssl/public/nsISSLStatus.idl). You can get it for a page loaded into a `<browser>` element or the current tab of a `<tabbrowser>` element (e.g. `gBrowser` if you want the `<tabbrowser>` element in the Firefox browser window) like this:

```js
var status = gBrowser.securityUI
                     .QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsISSLStatusProvider)
                     .SSLStatus;
if (status && !status.isUntrusted)
{
  alert("Cipher: " + status.cipherName);
  alert("Key length: " + status.keyLength);
}
```

Please don't look at the key length without looking at the cipher used - the key length alone is meaningless.

Comment: do u knw any other types to use with nsISSLSatus like satus.**cipherName** /satus.**keyLength** what else we can check with nsISSLsatus?